# How to get rating star value from mysql?

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

In my Worklight-based application, I have a rating value(int) stored in mysql. I have as JSON data the rating integer value.

```
{"storeId":1000,"zipcode":"600014","rating":3,}
```

Using Jquery I need to display that rating value as images of stars in the application.
If the value is 2, then I need to display 2 star images, and so on.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: basically you want to ask how to read this JSON  response , right ??

Answer (score 0):

It would've been helpful to see what you've implemented thus far (adapter implementation, client-side adapter invocation, ...).
Without it, I can only provide one possible way to get a value from from a database and display it.

It is assumed that:

- In your database, there is a 'stars' field and value
- In the common\images folder in your application, there is an image of a star
- You have [created a SQL adapter and configured it correctly](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v620/04_03_SQL_adapter_-_Communicating_with_SQL_database.pdf)

Implementation:

1. In common\index.html there is, for example, an empty `UL` element just so that the fetched data will be in a list:

   ```
       <ul id="usersAndStars"></ul>
   ```
2. In common\js\main.js, you invoke your adapter:

   ```
   // Of course, you can invoke it whenever you actually want to, and not like below...
   function wlCommonInit(){
       getStarsFromDatabase();
   }

   function getStarsFromDatabase() {
       var invocationData = {
           adapter: 'getStars',
           procedure: 'getStars'
       };

       WL.Client.invokeProcedure(
           invocationData,
           {
               onSuccess: displayStars,
               onFailure: failedGettingStars
           });
   }
   ```
3. Then you handle the response of the invocation, failure and success:

   ```
   function failedGettingStars() {
       alert("failure");
   }

   function displayStars(response) {
       var ul = $('#usersAndStars'); 
       var i, j, li;

       for (i = 0; i < response.invocationResult.resultSet.length; i += 1) {     
           // Create new <li> element and populate it
           li = $("<li/>").text("Item " + [i+1] + " has " + response.invocationResult.resultSet[i].stars + " stars: ");

           // Add images of a star
           // Note that this is purely applicative - instead of adding several img tags,
           // You could simply add an image showing 5 or 2 or 3 or however stars you want...
           // Or in any other way you want.
           for (j = 0; j < response.invocationResult.resultSet[i].stars; j += 1) {
               li.append("<img src='images/\star.png' alt='star'/>");
           }

           // Append the <li> element to the <ul> element
           ul.append(li);
       };
   }
   ```
4. In adapters\getStars\getStars-impl.js file:

   ```
   var selectStatement = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("select * from users");

   function getStars() {    
       return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
           preparedStatement : selectStatement,
           parameters : []
       });
   }
   ```
5. In adapters\getStars\getStars.xml file:

   ```
   ...
   ...
   ...
   <procedure name="getStars"/>
   ```

The end result:

[image]

Comment: I would use a single class with CSS (star as `background-image`) so you could insert only one element into the DOM and alter it's width with either CSS/JavaScript to display all the stars. This also saves on HTTP requests.

Comment: Yes, I agree. However, as noted in the code snippets the display of the stars can be optimized greatly. But this is not what the question is about; what the user really wanted to know is how to handle the Worklight adapter invocation.